# Difference between yum install --enablerepo=remi-php70 php and yum install --enablerepo=remi php70-php

Tags: yum

With `yum install --enablerepo=remi-php70 php`, I get

```
[/]# yum list installed | grep php
gd3php.x86_64                2.3.3-7.el7.remi       @remi-safe
php.x86_64                   7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-bcmath.x86_64            7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-cli.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-common.x86_64            7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-devel.x86_64             7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-fpm.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-gd.x86_64                7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-gmp.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-intl.x86_64              7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-json.x86_64              7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-mbstring.x86_64          7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-mcrypt.x86_64            7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-mysqlnd.x86_64           7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-opcache.x86_64           7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-pdo.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-pear.noarch              1:1.10.13-1.el7.remi   @remi-php70
php-pecl-apcu.x86_64         5.1.22-1.el7.remi.7.0  @remi-php70
php-pecl-apcu-bc.x86_64      1.0.5-1.el7.remi.7.0   @remi-php70
php-pecl-imagick-im6.x86_64  3.7.0-1.el7.remi.7.0   @remi-php70
php-process.x86_64           7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
php-xml.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi-php70
```

With `yum install --enablerepo=remi php70-php`, I get

```
[/]# yum list installed | grep php
gd3php.x86_64                      2.3.3-7.el7.remi      @remi
php70-php.x86_64                   7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-bcmath.x86_64            7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-cli.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-common.x86_64            7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-devel.x86_64             7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-fpm.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-gd.x86_64                7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-gmp.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-intl.x86_64              7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-json.x86_64              7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-mbstring.x86_64          7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-mcrypt.x86_64            7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-mysqlnd.x86_64           7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-opcache.x86_64           7.0.33-35.el7.remi     @remi
php70-php-pdo.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-pear.noarch              1:1.10.13-1.el7.remi  @remi
php70-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64         5.1.22-1.el7.remi     @remi
php70-php-pecl-apcu-bc.x86_64      1.0.5-1.el7.remi      @remi
php70-php-pecl-imagick-im6.x86_64  3.7.0-1.el7.remi      @remi
php70-php-process.x86_64           7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-php-xml.x86_64               7.0.33-35.el7.remi    @remi
php70-runtime.x86_64               2.0-1.el7.remi        @remi
```

So far I found some differences

- `yum install --enablerepo=remi php70-php` installs `php70-runtime` additionally.
- `yum install --enablerepo=remi php70-php` installs locally, like its php-fpm.conf locates at `/etc/opt/remi/php70/php-fpm.conf` whereas in the other senario, it locates at `/etc/php-fpm.conf`.

Just by the fact that `yum install --enablerepo=remi php70-php` installs its version separately, it feels like it manages its version better. It's similar to current project management trend, like now we install nodejs project dependencies locally.

Was I right above? And are there any other practical and crucial differences, like in the sense of upgrading php version later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [repository FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

- **php-*** are for default/single version installation (replace default system packages)
- **php70-php-*** are designed for multiple versions installation simultaneously

For proper installation configuration, the simplest way is to follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

Kind reminders:

- PHP 7.0 is [EOL](https://www.php.net/eol.php) since January 2019, even if my repository has security backports I heartily recommend using a [supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)
- EL-7 is close to its EOL in June 2024, so I heartily recommend using EL-8 or EL-9, especially for modern software, such as recent PHP versions